# Cakephp 3.6.14: Display html formatted text in text field

Tags: php, html, cakephp

I have a form with some text fields, I want to know if it is possible to display HTML formatted text in an editable text field.

This is the field:

```
echo $this->Form->control('instructions');
```

How I can display it HTML formatted? Do I need a `WYSIWYG Plugin` or there is another way?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will need to add something like CKEditor or TinyMCE to your project. Some potentially useful resources for you:

- https://github.com/CakeCoded/CkEditor
- http://thecoderain.blogspot.com/2017/07/cakephp-3x-add-text-editor-tinyMCE.html
- https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/framework-plugins/cakephp
- https://plugins.cakephp.org/packages?category=wysiwyg-editors

Answer (score 0):

Look at the html code generated with the browser inspector, and look at the id of the textarea you want to convert, then just write the necessary JS